# Strategies to ensure that each Kafka consumer has a different / unique group.id to implement publish-subscribe

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to implement a publish-subscribe model with Kafka where one topic will be read / consumed by many independent consumers.

From my understanding, each consumer identifies it self as a unique subscriber, by using a unique group.id

However, a malicious or faulty consumer B can steel consumer A's message if consumer B advertises it self with the same group.id as consumer A. Thus messages will be distributed between Consumer A and B which is not desired.

Are there any Kafka machanisms or strategies to prevent that from happening?

I was not able to find anyone discussing this question; makes me wonder if perhaps I misunderstood group.ids or there is some obvious solution that I missed. So sorry if this is a noob question, but many thanks for your time!

Comment: You could use ACLs and/or SASL to prevent bad actors

Comment: thanks @cricket_007, I think this may be the only viable option it seems ...

Answer (score 2):

What you want is something called **Manual Partition Assignment**. In this mode, the auto consumer rebalancing is turned off, so you have full control over which topic/partitions you're consuming from, and no consumer can "steal" messages from you, even if they are using the same exact consumer group.id.  Of course, the downside is, there is no auto consumer rebalancing in case any of the consumers go down.

From the official Javadocs (highlights mine):

> To use this mode, instead of subscribing to the topic using subscribe,
>   you just call assign(Collection) with the full list of partitions that
>   you want to consume.
>
> ```
>  String topic = "foo";
>  TopicPartition partition0 = new TopicPartition(topic, 0);
>  TopicPartition partition1 = new TopicPartition(topic, 1);
>  consumer.assign(Arrays.asList(partition0, partition1));   Once assigned, you can call poll in a loop, just as in the preceding
> ```
>
> examples to consume records.
>   The group that the consumer specifies is still used for committing
>   offsets, but now the set of partitions will only change with another
>   call to assign. **Manual partition assignment does not use group
>   coordination, so consumer failures will not cause assigned partitions
>   to be rebalanced. Each consumer acts independently even if it shares a
>   groupId with another consumer.** To avoid offset commit conflicts, you
>   should usually ensure that the groupId is unique for each consumer
>   instance.

Full docs here (look for **Manual Partition Assignment** section): https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

Comment: The "downside" of this is the loss of consumer rebalance tolerance, right?

Comment: Sure, that's implicit.  I'll make an edit so it's clear.

Comment: Hmm... in my case, I might want to partition the topic to N partitions now, N+1 later. So does this mean that I will need to update the config of the consumer when ever my partition count changes?

Comment: Yes, that's part of the tradeoffs when doing this kind of thing.  It's allowed, but is not the typical use-case Kafka was designed for.  Before consuming, you could issue a `listTopics` call, and that will get you current topics and partition info, and you could _then_ do the manual assignment.  Still, your consumers won't automatically be notified if there's more partitions available, you'll have to manually restart the consumers.

Comment: @mjuarez : but this "To avoid offset commit conflicts, you should usually ensure that the groupId is unique for each consumer instance." seems to suggest that I can still "steal" messages if one consumer, with the same group.id as another one, commits the read. Am I correct in this interpretation?