# Kafka Consumer taking total control of partitions and offsets?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a usecase where I have multiple end-users connected to my java based spring boot microservice via websocket.

```
User A --> WebsocketSession 1
User B --> WebsocketSession 2
```

Now in the backend, I have a bunch of Kafka Listeners receiving the data from partitions of the topic and broadcasting it to all the "Active" Websockets (in the above example User A and User B would receive the data). The "Active" websockets is a simple map stored in memory.

Now the challenge is if the service crashes and the users reconnect to a different instance, I need them to start receiving the messages from where they left off.

Looks like I need to take complete control of partitions and offsets here (ie manual commits and recording it in a persistent store)?

Is this too much of an overkill (ie doing things imperatively as opposed to the recommended approach)?

What's the recommended way for such use cases?

Comment: What is the 'recommended approach' you mention?

Answer (score 0):

> Now the challenge is if the service crashes and the users reconnect to
> a different instance, I need them to ***start receiving the messages
> from where they left off***.

Is this not already the default consumer behavior? Can you have a consumer group.id for each unique user and then get this behavior out of the box?

If you area already utilizing a lot of kafka listeners, then all of that code will most likely have to be redone to to manage offsets.

---

With that being said

I wrote a class that does something similar for "global" consumer behavior where I had to manually manage the consumer offsets and manually assign partitions. This should give you an idea of what is involved

The use case was: `create a consumer to pull all data from all partitions in a topic up until it hits the current offsets at time t`

So for example if you have 3 partitions with the end offset 100, 200, and 150 then the consumer will read from offset 0 to N for each partition where N=100,200,150 and then return a collection of results.

Using this as a baseline, you could modify the behavior to start from the last commit for the consumer group id (unique for each user), read and commit the offset for a consumer group manually. the exit condition could be the end of the websocket session.

Something else to note is that when you manually assign partitions as I have done you lose the consumer group balancing behavior.

```
/**
 * 
 * This class pulls an entire Kafka topic and then exits based on the latest
 * offsets in the topic
 * 
 * @author Fermi-4
 *
 * @param <K>
 * @param <T>
 */
@Slf4j
public class KafkaRunnerImpl<K, T> implements KafkaRunner<T> {

    final Deserializer<K> _keySerde;
    final Deserializer<T> _valueSerde;
    final String _bootstrapServers;
    final String _topic;
    final int _requestTimeout;
    final int _sampleTimeout;
    
    public KafkaRunnerImpl(Deserializer<K> _keySerde, Deserializer<T> _valueSerde, String _bootstrapServers, String _topic, int _requestTimeout,
            int _sampleTimeout) {
        super();
        this._topic = _topic;
        this._keySerde = _keySerde;
        this._valueSerde = _valueSerde;
        this._bootstrapServers = _bootstrapServers;
        this._requestTimeout = _requestTimeout;
        this._sampleTimeout = _sampleTimeout;
    }
    
    private Map<TopicPartition, Long> _endOffsets;
    
    /**
     * 
     * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52837302/strategies-to-ensure-that-each-kafka-consumer-has-a-different-unique-group-id
     * 
     * in order to ensure we get all of the data from the partitions of a topic we need 
     * to manually assign the partitions to the consumer.
     * 
     * There are tradeoffs to doing this and is not the intended use for kafka (see above)
     * 
     * 
     */
    public Collection<T> pull() {
        try(KafkaConsumer<K, T> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<K, T>(getConsumerProps())) {
        
            Collection<T> records = new ArrayList<T>();
        
            /*
             * subscribe to topic
             */
            
            List<PartitionInfo> info = consumer.partitionsFor(_topic);
            
            /*
             * manually assign the partitions
             */
             consumer.assign(info.stream().map(partitionInfo -> new TopicPartition(_topic, partitionInfo.partition())).collect(Collectors.toList()));
            
            /*
             * partitions belonging to this consumer
             */
            Set<TopicPartition> partitions = consumer.assignment();
            
            /*
             * seek the beginning of assigned partitions
             */
            consumer.seekToBeginning(partitions);
            
            /*
             * the target partition end offsets
             */
            _endOffsets = consumer.endOffsets(partitions);
            log.info(_endOffsets.toString());

            
            /*
             * start loop
             */
            while(comparePartitionOffsets(consumer)) {
                /*
                 * poll for messages
                 */
                ConsumerRecords<K, T> sample = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(_sampleTimeout));        
                
                for(TopicPartition partition : partitions) {
                    /*
                     * grab the records only from this partition
                     */
                    List<ConsumerRecord<K, T>> recordsForPartition = sample.records(partition);
                    
                    /*
                     * iterate through all the records and add to the collection 
                     * ONLY if the record offset is less than the target offset
                     * for current partition
                     */
                    for(ConsumerRecord<K, T> consumerRecord : recordsForPartition) {
                        log.debug("record offset: " + consumerRecord.offset() + " partition: " + consumerRecord.partition());
                        if(consumerRecord.offset() <= _endOffsets.get(partition)) {
                            records.add(consumerRecord.value());
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
        
            return records;
        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // handle the exception 
        }
        
        return null;
    }
    
    // compare current offsets to the target offsets, return false if offsets not met yet    
    private boolean comparePartitionOffsets(KafkaConsumer<K, T> consumer) {
        return !_endOffsets.keySet().stream().allMatch(tp -> {
            log.info("consumer: " +consumer.position(tp) + " target: " + _endOffsets.get(tp));
            boolean offsetsReached = consumer.position(tp) >= (_endOffsets.get(tp)-1);
            if(offsetsReached) log.info("Target offsets reached for partition: " + tp.partition());
            return offsetsReached;
        });
    }

    private Properties getConsumerProps() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "runner-group");
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, _requestTimeout); // polls until this timeout is reached then closes
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, _bootstrapServers);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, _valueSerde.getClass());
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, _keySerde.getClass());
        return properties;
    }



}
```